# Getting undefined method [] for nil:NilClass when trying to use string interpolation

Tags: ruby, string-interpolation

I'm new to coding in general and just starting Ruby. I'm using the Odin Project, and we have to create a tic tac toe game.  I'm trying to display the board, and I keep getting an undefined method [] for nil:NilClass error in the following code:

```
class Board
  attr_reader :display_board, :check_board

  def initialize
    @board = %w[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  end

  class << self
    attr_reader :board
  end

  def self.display_board
    puts '|-----------|'
    puts "| #{@board[0]} | #{@board[1]} | #{@board[2]} |" # error occurs on this line
    puts '|---+---+---|'
    puts "| #{@board[3]} | #{@board[4]} | #{@board[5]} |"
    puts '|---+---+---|'
    puts "| #{@board[6]} | #{@board[7]} | #{@board[8]} |"
    puts '|-----------|'
  end
```

I had it working at some point, and I don't know what I did that broke it. Any hints?

Comment: `@board` is an instance variable but `self.display_board` defines a class method and a class has no access to instance variables. How do you call your code?

Comment: Hint: Write Unit tests for ALL your methods. Use GIT version control. When your unit test has passed, commit your code. Then when you "break it" you can find out what changed. For unit test you can use built in [Ruby MiniTest](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-trunk/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest.html).  Also see [How To Use Git](https://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial)

Comment: @spickermann - I called it from within another class using Board.display_board. I know that part works because it puts the first line correctly.  I think you're on to something with the instance variable and class method.. that kept coming up in my google searches, but I wasn't figuring out how to fix it.

Comment: @lacostenycoder  I do use GIT and GitHub, and have a previous version saved, but I probably don't commit often enough and since than have gone down the rabbit hole of fixing one problem makes another, and fixing that one makes another one, and so on a so forth, so there were more than a few differences to figure out.  The Odin Project teaches us how to write tests, but I haven't gotten that far yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways you could put it:
1.

```
    class Board
      def self.board
        %w[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
      end

      def self.display_board
  
        puts '|-----------|'
        puts "| #{Board.board[0]} | #{Board.board[1]} | #{Board.board[2]} |" 
          # error occurs on this line
        puts '|---+---+---|'
        puts "| #{Board.board[3]} | #{Board.board[4]} | #{Board.board[5]} |"
        puts '|---+---+---|'
        puts "| #{Board.board[6]} | #{Board.board[7]} | #{Board.board[8]} |"
        puts '|-----------|'

       end

   p Board.display_board #access class methods directly
```

2. Another is this:

   ```
    class Board2

       attr_reader :board

       def initialize
           @board = %w[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
       end

       def display_board
          puts '|-----------|'
         puts "| #{board[0]} | #{board[1]} | #{board[2]} |" # error occurs on this line
         puts '|---+---+---|'
         puts "| #{board[3]} | #{board[4]} | #{board[5]} |"
         puts '|---+---+---|'
         puts "| #{board[6]} | #{board[7]} | #{board[8]} |"
        end
       end

      board = Board2.new #create Board2 object
      p board.display_board #access public methods
   ```

Comment: since OP is "new to coding" you should explain the ideas behind both suggestions and what advantages or disadvantages there may be to each.

Comment: I would prefer the second version. Because as soon as you start the changing values on the board you do want that on one instance of the board and not the Board class.